# Runtime error when executing my code in ExtendScript Toolkit

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extendscript

I want to create a UI that I can use to control certain parameters of an After Effects project, such as opacity or position etc..

I have created a UI with https://scriptui.joonas.me/
It has a slider. Now I want to give the slider a function, which actually worked out. However, if I run my code in the Extend Script toolkit, I will receive a non-specified warning, once I move the slider.

If I run the script within After Effects, it will change the parameter, but only AFTER I close the UI. In fact, I cannot click on anything within my After Effects composition, when I run the script.
What is the newbie mistake that I made?

Here's the code that I have:

```
// DIALOG
// ======
var dialog = new Window("dialog"); 
    dialog.text = "Dialog"; 
    dialog.orientation = "column"; 
    dialog.alignChildren = ["center","top"]; 
    dialog.spacing = 10; 
    dialog.margins = 16; 

// ZOOMER
// ======
var Zoomer = dialog.add("panel", undefined, undefined, {name: "Zoomer"}); 
    Zoomer.text = "Zoom"; 
    Zoomer.orientation = "column"; 
    Zoomer.alignChildren = ["left","top"]; 
    Zoomer.spacing = 10; 
    Zoomer.margins = 10; 

var slider1 = Zoomer.add("slider", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, {name: "slider1"}); 
    slider1.minvalue = 0; 
    slider1.maxvalue = 100; 
    slider1.value = 100; 

var KeyframeMaker = Zoomer.add("button", undefined, undefined, {name: "KeyframeMaker"}); 
    KeyframeMaker.text = "Keyframe"; 

 dialog.Zoomer.slider1.onChanging = function() {
       app.project.item(24).layer("World Map").property("ADBE Transform Group").property("ADBE Opacity").setValue(slider1.value);
                  };        
dialog.Zoomer.KeyframeMaker.onClick = function() {
                    alert("it works");
                    };
dialog.show();
```

Comment: No need for all the caveats about your experience level. Many of the users here are new to coding, and we all were at some point. Welcome.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. I want to add that at first I also put just an alert to test the slider - and it worked. In fact the error consists of a window asking "delete runtime error" - Yes/No?" It seems the runtime error appears only with this part of the code: app.project.item(24).layer("World Map").property("ADBE Transform Group").property("ADBE Opacity").setValue(slider1.value);
                  };